# Guardas datos de multiples filas en mysql con checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Espero que podáis ayudarme. Quisiera marcar en una tabla varias filas para que se borren de la base de datos y se guarden en otra table. He conseguido hacerlo con una sola fila, pero quisiera poder hacerlo de forma masiva, marcando las filas a guardar en la otra tabla con un chekboxguarden en la base de datos. Las marco con el ckeckbox me sale el mensaje de que se ha guardado correctamente, pero no las guarda. Este es el código de la tabla y del checkbox.

Muhcas gracias de antemano

```
<form method="post" action="guardarAltIncomplITKBackup.php">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" name="borrar" value="Eliminar Registros"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" class="btn btn-primary">
                         
 <input type="submit"class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" value="Guardar Registros"> 
                        
</div> 
    <table class="table display table-striped table-bordered" id="mitabla" border="1" 
 style="width:100%" >

        <thead style='background-color:#A0A0A0;'>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Marcar para eliminar</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Nombre de Cliente</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Zona de Ventas</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Ramo </th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Fecha de Env&#237;o al Cliente</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>D&#237;as Pendientes del Cliente</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Editar</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Borrar</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Guardar</th>
    </thead>

    <?php while($d= $datos->fetch_object()):?>

  
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="<?php echo $d->id_altIncomp; ?>"class="check"></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $d->nombreCliente;?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $d->zv; ?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $d->ramo; ?></td>
        <td align="right"><?php echo $d->fechaEnvioCliente; ?></td>
        
        <td align="center"><?php 
            $datetime1 = date_create($d->fechaActual);
            $datetime2 = date_create($d->fechaEnvioCliente);
            $diasPendCliente = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
            $differenceFormat = '%a';
            echo $diasPendCliente->format($differenceFormat); ?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="modificarAltIncompITK.php?id_altIncomp=<?php echo $d-> id_altIncomp; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#" data-href="eliminarAltIncompITK.php?id_altIncomp=<?php echo $d->id_altIncomp; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="modificarAltIncomplITKBackup.php?id_altIncomp=<?php echo $d->id_altIncomp; ?>" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></a></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php  
 
$checkbox = $_POST['check'] ;  
if ($_POST["Submit" ]=="Submit")  
{  
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof ($checkbox);$i++) {  
$sql="INSERT INTO altasincompletasBackup (nombreCliente, zv, ramo, fechaEnvioCliente, diasPendCliente) VALUES ('".$checkbox[$i]. "')";  
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); 
}  
echo "Record is inserted";  
}  
?>      
        </table>
    
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes obtener los campos por nombre, no por ID

```
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="<?php echo $d->id_altIncomp; ?>"class="check"></td>
```

El nombre del campo es casilla y los corchetes harán que se cargue en un arreglo. Al procesar, primero verificas que se envió el formulario y después obtienes los checkboxes marcados:

```
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit") {  
    $checkbox = $_POST['casilla']; // "casilla", no "check"
    for($i = 0; $i < count($checkbox); $i++) {  
        $sql="INSERT INTO altasincompletasBackup (nombreCliente, zv, ramo, fechaEnvioCliente, diasPendCliente) VALUES ('".$checkbox[$i]. "')";  
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); 
    }
    echo "Record is inserted";  
}
```

El problema ahora es que no se va a realizar la inserción, porque estás especificando varios campos y proporcionando solo un valor que, de hecho, tampoco corresponde a ninguno de esos campos.

Lo primero que debes hacer es leer los registros de la tabla original:

```
$sqlMarcados = 'SELECT * FROM tablaOriginal WHERE id_altIncomp IN (' . implode(', ', $checkbox) . ')';
```

Si marcaste elementos con ID 4, 10 y 18, la consulta quedaría:

```
SELECT * FROM tablaOriginal WHERE id_altIncomp IN (4, 10, 18)
```

Ya solo queda ejecutar la consulta y recorrer los resultados para insertar, de preferencia, usando [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para que los datos sean escapados correctamente y evitar errores, además, de hacerlo de forma segura.

```
// Entrar solo si se está procesando formulario y se marcó al menos 1 checkbox
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit" && count($_POST['casilla']) > 0) {  
    // Obtener checkboxes marcados
    $checkbox = $_POST['casilla'];
    // Crear consulta
    $sqlMarcados = 'SELECT * FROM tablaOriginal WHERE id_altIncomp IN (' . implode(', ', $checkbox) . ')';
    // Ejecutar consulta
    $paraInsertar = $mysql->query($sqlMarcados);
    // Recorrer resultados
    while($r = $paraInsertar->fetchObject()) {
        // Usar consulta preparada (INCLUIR id_altIncomp)
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO altasincompletasBackup (id_altIncomp, nombreCliente, zv, ramo, fechaEnvioCliente, diasPendCliente) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        // Preparar consulta
        $st = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        // Enlazar valores
        $st->bind_param('isssss', $r->id_altIncomp, $->nombreCliente, $->zv, $r->ramo, r->fechaEnvioCliente, $r->diasPendCliente);
        // Ejecutar
        $st->execute(); 
    }
    echo "Record is inserted";  
}
```

Te recomiendo leer también [mysqli_stmt::bind_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) para saber más acerca de cómo se deben enlazar los valores.

**Nota:** No copies y peques este código, aparte de que el nombre de `tablaOriginal` seguramente no se corresponde con el tuyo, no tengo forma de probarlo. Lee bien la respuesta, así como los enlaces a documentación y, cuando lo entiendas, entonces sí lo aplicas en tu código.

Comment: Otro problema que podría presentarse es que ya exista en la tabla uno de los registros que se van a insertar y obtengas un error por índice duplicado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta. Seguiré tu consejo de leer bien la respuesta y la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar haciendo un foreach.

```
if ($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit") {
        $checkbox = $_POST['casilla'];
        foreach ($checkbox as $key => $value) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO altasincompletasBackup (nombreCliente, zv, ramo, fechaEnvioCliente, diasPendCliente) VALUES (......)";
            $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        }
        echo "Record is inserted";
    }
```